# Apache 2.4 mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm in the process of learning about apache.

I have my admin views set up in directories like this:

```
/admin/views/(component)/index.html
```

so I set up a rewrite rule to that looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-z]+)$ /admin/views/$1/index.html [L]
```

so that if someone goes to `http://mywebsite/admin/user` it should take them to `http://mywebsite/admin/views/user/index.html`. I have confirmed that mod_rewite works using a very simple rewrite and I know that the direct path to those resources works without the mod_rewrite.

Unfortunately, I'm just getting a 404 error.

How do I write this RewriteRule, what am I missing?

Comment: Where did you place this .htaccess?

Comment: In the /admin/ directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule in your `admin/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /admin/

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ views/$1/index.html [L]
```

Comment: It's so simple, yet I now have dozens more questions.